# filtering the table based on the timerange for every record in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, let's say one tagging another one in telemetry table. tagging table contain case_id,machine_id,from_date,to_date and fault.telemetry table contains columns id,machine_id,telemetry_time,current,health_score of 6months data.
I want to get a one result set which contains data of telemetry data,filtered by tagging table's machine_id,from_date and to_date of every row.

[Check for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=165eb3f3e8570c3d721acf95097e0e93)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: is there any  better way to achieve it on a huge table with 10m rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for a `join`?

```
select tm.*
from telemetry tm join
     tagging t
     on tm.machine_id = t.machine_id and
        tm.telemetry_time between t.start_date and t.end_date;
```